# Model not linking to table in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-migrations

I have a table named tasks and a model named Task. In my controller method when i run this piece of code

```
     <?php

        namespace App\Http\Controllers;

        use DB;
        //use app\Task;
        use DateTime;
        use Illuminate\Http\Request;
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

        class Task_Controller extends Controller
        {
        //
             public function decide()
             {

             if ($input=="show all task")
             {
                  //$rows=DB::table('task')->get();
                  $rows=\App\Task::all();
                  foreach($rows as $values)
                  {
                     foreach($values as $key=>$val)
                     echo "$key  :  $val <br>";
                     echo "<br><br>";
                  }
              }
         }
```

It gives me following error:
**SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: tasks (SQL: select * from "tasks")**

That is the model should have linked to the **task** table instead it is linked to the **tasks** table Why??.

How to make model gets linked to a specific table.

My model class code goes like this

```
       namespace App;

       use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

       class Task extends Model
       {
          //
       }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should name your table `tasks`, this is the best option.

Another way to fix this is to use [`$table` property](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#defining-models):

```
protected $table = 'task';
```

> Note that we did not tell Eloquent which table to use for our Flight model. By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified. So, in this case, Eloquent will assume the Flight model stores records in the  flights table. You may specify a custom table by defining a table property on your model

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#defining-models

Answer (score 3):

By default, the table name is the plural of the class name. If you want it to point to a different table, then in your model, add

```
protected $table = 'task';
```

Answer (score 2):

By default laravel pluralizes the model names to be be the table names unless stated otherwise in the model by.

`protected $table = 'task';`